# count category item algorithm with insert new item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

the code below work to retrieve the total number of each category, where I have 4. I count the length of all existing category through loop, and then use switch to collect all of them. it worked, I gave me like a= 3, b=2, c= 10 and d=20.

But It doesn't work when I run this function upon new value inserted. For example new object inserted, the function recalculate and gave wrong value.

I wrote this

```
            $scope.countNote = 0;
            $scope.countQuote = 0;
            $scope.countProject = 0;
            $scope.countSkill = 0;

            $scope.countState = function () {

                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.postItem.length; i++)                             {
                    $loopObj = $scope.postItem[i].category_id;


                    switch ($loopObj) {
                        case '1':
                            $scope.countNote++;
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            $scope.countQuote++;
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            $scope.countProject++;
                            break;
                        case '4':
                            $scope.countSkill++;
                            break;
                    }
                }



            }
```

Comment: how you are adding a new value ?

Comment: @Sarath http://i.imgur.com/wKSy8J9.png I console.log($post.item).. I use push with for front-end

Comment: yes so after each push u need to initialize the count with calling countState function

Comment: @Sarath tried, didn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the initializer inside function, and call it after each push

```
$scope.countState = function () {
            $scope.countNote = 0;
            $scope.countQuote = 0;
            $scope.countProject = 0;
            $scope.countSkill = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < $scope.postItem.length; i++)                             {
                    $loopObj = $scope.postItem[i].category_id;
                    switch ($loopObj) {
                        case '1':
                            $scope.countNote++;
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            $scope.countQuote++;
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            $scope.countProject++;
                            break;
                        case '4':
                            $scope.countSkill++;
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: the logic is fine, I did that too, but the value didn't update instantly, maybe scope problem?

Comment: I found the problem. It's because the data I use in the loop, required I load from backend, that's why the number didn't update. So I run the onload to get my data and count. but that is heavy and slow, I'm finding ways to do it wholely front end.